# Unwind in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, aggregation, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-net

I am currently having the below index in ElasticSearch

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "type" : {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        },
        "id" : {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        },
        "nestedTypes": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "nestedTypeId":{
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "nestedType":{
              "type": "text",
              "fielddata": true
            },
            "isLead":{
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "share":{
              "type": "float"
            },
            "amount":{
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need the nested types to be displayed in a HTML table along with the `id` and `type` fields in each row.

I am trying to achieve something similar to [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in MongoDB.

I have tried the reverse nested aggregation as below

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
"NestedTypes": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "nestedTypes"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "NestedType": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "nestedTypes.nestedType",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Details": {
          "reverse_nested": {}, 
          "aggs": {
            "type": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "type"
              }
            },
            "id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "id"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

But the above returns only one field from the `nestedTypes`, but I need all of them.

Also, I need sorting and pagination for this table. Could you please let me know how this can be achieved in ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ElasticSearch does not support this operation out of the box. When a request was raised to implement the same in git, the below response was given:

> We discussed it in Fixit Friday and agreed that we won't try to
>   implement it due to the fact that we can't think of a way to support
>   such operations efficiently.
>
> The only ideas that we thought were reasonable boiled down to having
>   another index that stores the same data but flattened. Depending on
>   your use-case, you might be able to maintain those two views in
>   parallel or would only maintain the one you have today, then
>   materialize a flattened view of the data when you need it and throw it
>   away after you are done querying. In both cases, this requires
>   client-side logic.

The link to the request is [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28836)